# How do I edit Superfish menu content?

Tags: jquery, menuitem, superfish

I inherited a website that uses Superfish for menu items. Seems like a cool little plugin. I need to change the menu across the whole site. Do I simply edit the HTML on each page, or is there a central way that Superfish prefers you to change menu content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the HTML.

You check the source on this page to see it: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples